# Python for loop to iterate two times

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is example code:

```
List1 = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
range_value = len(List1) * 2
for x in range(0, range_value):
   if x == 0 or x == 1:
       for y in List1[1]:
           print y
   if x == 2 or x == 3:
       for y in List1[2]

   if x == 4 or x == 5:
       for y in List1[2]
```

This is manual steps defineing if statement in case I have big values like 100 or 1000. Its difficult, Please help me with  any logic for this. first two values should use List[1] and next two values List[2] and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Use a third loop:

```
for x in List1:
    for _ in [0,1]:
        for y in x:
            ...
```

This iterates over each element of `List1` twice, as in the original code, without explicit index wrangling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
for y in List1[x//2]
```

It's a bit hard to tell, since you started at index 1 instead of index 0, but apparently want to use every element of the list.  You may need `[x//2 + 1]`.

Another possible enhancement is to double-step your outer loop:

```
for x in range(0, range_value, 2):
```